# Perl Script: how File::Tail function able to read binary(TCPDUMP) file?

Tags: perl, logging, snort

anyone can give me some opinion about this code?

```
#!/usr/local/bin/perl
use File::Tail;

$file = File::Tail -> new("/var/log/snort/snort.log.1301090101");
while(defined($line=$file ->read))
{
   print $line;
}
```

since the log file is binary format so i try modify code like this

```
#!/usr/local/bin/perl
use File::Tail;

$file = File::Tail -> new("/var/log/snort/snort.log.1301090101");
open(my $LF, "-|", "/usr/local/bin/snort -r $file") or die "$!";
while(defined($line=$file ->read))
{
   print $line;
}
```

this code seem have some syntax error..isn't possible to combine pipe and file tail function? isn't `file::tail` function already include `open()` method?

2nd question is about the `$file = File::Tail -> new(<Filename>);`
`<Filename>` seem must the single file and must point to the particular file name...
if i have 3 file: `snort.log.1301090101`, `snort.log.1301090102` and `snort.log.1301090102` in same directory, isn't possible using a single `File::Tail` function to read all of that or the file inside the directory?

Comment: It would be a good idea to include the exact syntax error, including line numbers or stack trace, produced by the code.

Comment: `snort` expects a file name, but (poorly named) `$file` is a file handle. This can be a bit tricky to fix, but using [IPC::Run](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?IPC::Run) would be useful if you actually do need File::Tail.

Comment: Which leads to my question for you: Do you actually need File::Tail? I mean, are the logs files really growing? And if so, under what condition do you want to stop sending from the first file and start sending from the second file? It's not like `snort` will be able to make any sense of the file if you interleave them.

Comment: actually in my case there will be a lot of log file create...because max size of log file is 128MB...so when i running the coding how the program know that which file is the latest one?

Comment: somemore using /usr/local/bin/snort -r $file just able to display snort log file nicely, will not cannot display the content in word...

Answer (score 1):

As explained in your first question: **You can not simply read these files directly**. They are in a binary format, not text. You can not use `File::Tail`.

You can pipe the output of the actual snort process that reads those logs to perl, as has been shown. If it doesn't offer a "tail" type option, you can't tail them.

There is an old perl module [Net::TcpDumpLog](http://search.cpan.org/~bdgregg/Net-TcpDumpLog/TcpDumpLog.pm) that might let you read the data directly if it still works, but it can not tail the logs either.

The only way to tail them would be to change your snort config to output ASCII logs, but you may run into problems with it being able to keep up wit the packet stream.